# Client calling an server's event during the OnConnectedAsync method of SignalR hub in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, signalr, webapi

On OnConnectedAsync method of a Hub, I am calling an event of the client called OnCheckSession which calls the event called StartSession in the server.

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    // This event calls an event called StartSession inside
    await Clients.Caller.OnCheckSession();
    
    // Other logic which is dependent on the StartSession
}

public async Task<Guid> StartSession() 
{
    // Other logic
}
```

However, StartSession is always being called after the OnConnectedAsync. I have read some articles that say the client can call the event of the server only after the OnConnectedAsync.

Is there any way that another event of the server is called during the OnConnectedAsync?